# Character will not jump after touching in JS

Tags: javascript, collision-detection, game-development

I am programming collision detection in JS for a platformer. For some reason, when my character touches the ground on the top, it won't jump again. Here's my code:

```
if (isCollideY(platforms[i].getBoundingClientRect(), document.getElementById('spriteNotReal').getBoundingClientRect()) == true) {
                if (falling == true && (jumping == false)) {
                            moveY = platforms[i].getBoundingClientRect().y + 3;
                            momentumY = 0;
                            onSolidGround = true;
                        }
            }
```

```
if (event.code == 'KeyW' && (moveY <= 300)) { 
            moveY += 1;
            move (moveX, moveY);
            momentumY = momentumY + 20;
            onSolidGround = false;
            falling = false;
            jumping = true;
        }
```

```
else if (onSolidGround == false) {
        if (momentumY < 0) {
            falling = true;
        }
        else if (momentumY > 0) {
            jumping = true;
        }
        else {
            jumping = false;
        }
        moveX += momentumX / 3 + 1;
        document.getElementById("spriteNotReal").src = "jumpmain.gif";
    }
```

Comment: can you provide a minimal reproducible example?

Comment: Did that. I edited and added physics

Answer (score 2, accepted):

My problem was somewhat stupid. After checking the input code, I realized that the jump wasn't happening because it would only jump while on the "platform" I set up to test, not while it was actually on a platform. Here's the improved code:

```
if (event.code == 'KeyW' && (onSolidGround == true)) { 
            moveY += 1;
            move (moveX, moveY);
            momentumY = momentumY + 20;
            onSolidGround = false;
            falling = false;
            jumping = true;
        }
```